# MyBatis cannot work with joda DateTime?

Tags: java, oracle, datetime, jodatime, mybatis

I'm using **MyBatis** 3.2, and want to map Oracle `DATE` data type to Java `org.joda.time.DateTime` data type.

Here is my configuration:

```
<resultMap id="something" type="com.myself.SomeClass">
  <result property="creationDate" column="CREATION_DATE" javaType="org.joda.time.DateTime" />
</resultMap>
```

But I get following error:

```
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException
         : Error parsing SQL Mapper Configuration. 
Cause    : org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException
         : Error parsing Mapper XML. 
Cause    : java.lang.IllegalStateException
         : No typehandler found for property creationDate
```

Is my configuration correct? Or is it caused by my Oracle data type is `DATE` instead of `DATETIME`? Does MyBatis support joda DateTime?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need to use TypeResolver to handle JodaTime to Oracle DateTime. 
I had experience with this with MyBatis with MySQL and you might use this is a guide that might help you with your issue.

I used this github project as guide on how to use TypeResolver: https://github.com/LukeL99/joda-time-mybatis

And in one of my mappers, I have this code:

```
<result column="expiryDate" property="expiryDate" javaType="org.joda.time.DateTime" typeHandler="org.joda.time.mybatis.handlers.DateTimeTypeHandler"/>
```

The org.joda.time.mybatis.handlers.DateTimeTypeHandler is class from the github project I posted.

I hope this would help guide you.

Answer (score 2):

There is org.mybatis:mybatis-typehandlers-jsr310 for java 8 DateTime support.
I've copied needed classes to my project and ported them to JodaTime.
After that you can use type handlers in select statements and result definitions as usual.

```
@Select("select p.transaction_id from dly_mstr_curr_trd_prg p "
        + "where p.start_time < #{threshold, typeHandler=org.apache.ibatis.type.LocalDateTimeTypeHandler} "
        + "and failure_reason is null")
Collection<BigDecimal> selectStaleNotFailedTransactions(@Param("threshold") LocalDateTime threshold);
```

or

```
@Result(property = "transaction.transactionPostingDate", column = "TXN_PSTG_D", typeHandler=LocalDateTimeTypeHandler.class),
```

Here is example of ported class:

```
/**
 * @author Tomas Rohovsky
 */
public class LocalDateTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, LocalDate parameter, JdbcType jdbcType)
            throws SQLException {
        ps.setDate(i, Date.valueOf(parameter.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")));
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        Date date = rs.getDate(columnName);
        return getLocalDate(date);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        Date date = rs.getDate(columnIndex);
        return getLocalDate(date);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDate getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        Date date = cs.getDate(columnIndex);
        return getLocalDate(date);
    }

    private static LocalDate getLocalDate(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : LocalDate.parse(date.toLocalDate().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think MyBatis don't support Joda DateTime. It maybe caused by mybatis couldn't serialize Joda DateTime object into correct format for JDBC sql. So, you must use Java type "Date".

Comment: You can use JodaTime with MyBatis